# Javascript variable from framework jQuery EasyUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

Currently I am working on [jeasyui.com framework](http://jeasyui.com/).

I have the following code for my dropdown menu:

When I am working inside the framework and a form this will output the value what I like to have in a javascript var :

```
<input name="Account" type="" class="" readonly="True" data-options="min:0,precision:2">
```

My question is does somebody know how I get the value from the input into a JavaScript variable what I can use for the code below.

```
var AccountID = ???

<select name="">
    <script>

    for (var i=0;i<Accounts.length;i++)
    {

        var str1 = Accounts[i];
        var chunks = str1.split("#");

        var Selected = "";
        if (chunks[1] == AccountID) 
        {
            var Selected = "Selected";
        }

        document.write("<option " + Selected + " value='" + chunks[1] + "'>" + chunks[0] + "</option>");
    }

    </script>   

</select>
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: [Documentation](http://jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#)

Comment: any idea were I have too look for? Parser?

Comment: honestly, I was unsure what you were asking above. That's why I didn't attempt to assist.  If you could elaborate in your question i'd be happy to take a stab at it.

Comment: I found something like this  
 <script>
 
var AccountID = document.getElementsByName("#Account").value; 

document.write(AccountID);
 
 
 
  
     </script>

Comment: My question is because I am very new with jquery and javascript how can i retrieve the value from the input name Account and store it to an var.. I think I have to work with document.getElementsByName

Comment: oh like this in jquery `var nameOfVariable = $('#theIdOfTheInput').val();` hope that helps.  Or with only name attribute `var nameOfVariable = $('[name="ElementNameHere"]').val();`

Comment: Thanks I do this :        <input name="Account" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
        
        <script>
  
  var AccountID = $('[Name="Account"]').val('')
  document.write(AccountID)
  </script>
        
        
        <select> But gives back [object Object] :-(

Comment: The idea was to setup an drop down menu inside a dialog, everything works but only the account should be selected of the acount what is opening in the dialog, I am going to use the standard combobox from easyui, maybe that work

Comment: um I think you are going about this the wrong way...You have a select (combobox) when the user changes the option selected you want to display something?  is that the main idea? or am i missing something?  This is a trivial task.